# How to set Portlet Preferences via JavaScript

Tags: liferay, portlet

I am currently using ExtJS 3.4 to create the components of my portlet, and upon saving I wish to set the information into PortletPreferences. I understand how to set and get them via the Java code, but I am struggling to set and get the preferences via JavaScript.

I encode my JavaScript object by using Ext.encode(), but then I am stuck on saving that JSON String.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless LifeRay provides an AJAX API to save portlet preferences you will need to create something similar yourself.

The `serveResource` method is there to help manage AJAX requests for portlets. You can send the portlet preferences you want saved to a resourceURL and process them serverside in the `serveResource` method.

That's the closest way you can save them via JavaScript. Otherwise the typical method is to submit a form to an ActionURL and save the preferences in a `processAction` method.